# Under what law were the Republic protestors initially detained?

Tags: united-kingdom, england-and-wales, police, false-arrest

The detention of the Republic protestors at the coronation is [reported so](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/may/09/it-massively-backfired-republicanism-in-spotlight-after-arrests):

> At around 6am on the morning of the coronation, Smith and his colleagues brought down the amplifiers and megaphones from their Premier Inn hotel on St Martin’s Lane to Trafalgar Square. Then they returned outside the hotel to unload a large rental van full of placards. “I managed to get one of those bundles out onto the tailgate and I turn around and these police officers come in, three or four of them, but then all of a sudden all the others come out of a van, wanting to know what we were doing.”
>
> Smith was ushered away from the van. It was about 6.40am. “I said: ‘We have been talking to senior officers.’ And he said: ‘Who?’ And I said: ‘Mr. Kirby’, and he clearly recognised that and seemed a bit disappointed. And then I went to phone the liaison officer. And he said: ‘I’m now detaining you,’ and I went: ‘I’m just gonna stay on the phone.’ He just said: ‘What are you doing? I’m detaining you.’ And he just grabbed my wrist and took my phone off me.”
>
> Plastic packs were also found in the van containing 10 adjustable luggage straps, the type to keep bulging suitcases together, but which Smith was going to use to hold the placards onto trolleys as they were pushed down to Trafalgar Square. He was arrested for possession of lock-on devices and then all six of his group were put in a police van and taken to Walworth police station, in Kennington.

The initial detention occurred sometime prior to the discovery of luggage straps, therefore the initial detention cannot have been an arrest.  The other form of detention I am aware of is stop and search.  The legality of this seems to be defined/ensured by the GOWISELY acronym, [described by the police here](https://www.met.police.uk/SysSiteAssets/foi-media/metropolitan-police/policies/stop-and-account-search-powers-prior-to-arrest-standard-operating-procedure-sop) and few elements are present, in particular the information that must be provided and the use of force which must be used only as a "last resort" if absolutely necessary.

Under what powers were the Republic protestors detained and "use of force" used during the coronation?

For information, [this is what he was arrested for](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/8568b6eb940908f78483f1a4c19c19f94c739f03/0_0_1600_900/master/1600.jpg?width=620&quality=45&dpr=2&s=none) and [this is how many staff they had to provide any required information](https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/2c7c33a2e4efb90c9a73467d4e773eac3f034f27/60_0_1800_1080/master/1800.jpg?width=620&quality=45&dpr=2&s=none).

Comment: In police states, it is always legal for the police to arrest anyone who threatens power structures, for any reason or no reason.

Comment: Note that a peaceful arrest is not exactly "use of force", in fact the reason people get arrested peacefully at all is precisely because it avoids using force and then having to get arrested anyway

Comment: @user253751 "he grabbed my wrist" is legally a use of force as I understand it.

Comment: I don't think it's clear from the reporting, not in the mainstream media anyway. I imagine the police power to detain was for stop and search for something which could be used to commit a crime or for being in a designated area. If Republic sue the police and it comes to court then the court will hear more details about the circumstances.

Comment: As always in such cases, the useful question is not "is the police allowed to do ____ ?", but rather "what happens if/when the police does ____ anyway?".

Comment: From the linked Guardian article, *"Smith and the others were arrested for conspiracy to cause a public nuisance but were all released without charge."* ─ does that answer your question, or are you asking which law makes "conspiracy to cause a public nuisance" a criminal offence?

Comment: @kaya3 No.  That was later after they searched the van and found the straps.  The question is under what power the initial detention and use of force was under.